# Image blob Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Tags: php, laravel, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to retrieve an image saved as a blob but I keep getting this error "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" when I try to return it as JSON using Laravel 5.4. What is wrong and how can I fix it?

`database.php` mysql configuration

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
```

Retrieving the image

```
public function getpic()
{
    $pic = DB::connection('mysql')
            ->table('itempictures')
            ->select('picture')
            ->get();

    return response()->json($pic);
}
```

The `collation` of the table is `latin1_swedish_ci`

[image]

The `collation` of the column itself is `null`

[image]

`print_r` of the image
[image]

`var_dump of the image`[image]

`dd` of the image
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to know what is wrong

Comment: I think your assumption about encoding is wrong, encoding is about human readable text, not about binary (large) objects. I mean transcoding should not happen anywhere in the chain. And collation is about ordering text with an encoding, it also has nothing to do with blobs.

Comment: @Code4R7 Sorry I'm not following. Are you saying nothing is wrong the data?

Comment: The cause of the problem is not in your database. An image is binary data without encoding, it must not be parsed as encoded data. This is what seems to be happening when you try to return it as JSON (Unicode). Perhaps you could share how you put the image data into a JSON string?

Comment: @Code4R7 `response()->json($pic)` the full code is the second set of code in the OP. I've also tried `response()->json(['pic' => $pic], 200,['Content-type'=> 'application/json; charset=utf-8']);`

Comment: The error is a generic one from [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which happens when you feed binary data to it. According to [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#file-responses), you should try `response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);`, which is not JSON.

Comment: Perhaps [toJSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-json) would help?

Comment: `toJSON` didn't work. For `response()->file($pathToFile, $headers)` would `$pathToFile` be `$pic` in my case? And should I set any headers?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to json decode a binary file, instead you should response with the raw image binary data and modify the response content headers with some image type, like for example:

```
public function getImage($id)
{
    if($ehtufile = EhtuFile::find($id))
    {
        return response($ehtufile->filedata, 200)->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    } else
    {
        // TODO: No image found:...
        $arRes = ['res' => 'Error', 'text' => 'Slide Show Image not found'];
        return "nope";
    }
}
```

I hope that this will help!,

David Lyons